# Copy Fedora 28 BTRFS from Single Drive to Motherboard RAID(1) and make bootable

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, fedora, btrfs

I have a bootable Fedora 28 system running on a single drive (sdc), using BTRFS.

I used to have F24 running on my Raid-1 mirror, now I would like to transfer the 28 to the Raid-1 mirror.

The RAID-1 is currently configured via the motherboard controller as an empty RAID device (sda & sdb) "/dev/md126" in fdisk and gparted, and RAID-1 Array "/dev/md/Mirror1_0" in gnome-disks.

I thought that I could simply dd the single (sdc) drive to the raid (md126), and I can, but the RAID boot dumps me into repair.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems like your process is different than the one I have been messing with , but  I know that for whatever reason, when I DD a 32gb usb into a source iso file to later be distributed it works *ONLY* when going to another 32gb source. If I try using the 32gb source iso file to install on a 64gb usb it doesnt work. Again i'm not sure if this is a similar issue but thought it could be worth a shot to point out! Another reason is that I find it oddly similar to my case as my issue is also that it boots into emergency mode in the cases that it doesn't work! Hope this helps somehow!

Comment: Rick, at the risk of derailing my own question. 

When you dd the the source 32gb (/dev/sd(f) no partition number) to a "file", it's a raw or binary content file, not an iso although you could call it that if you like.

When you "install?" the file to a 64GB you dd the file back to the raw drive (/dev/sd(f) no partition number), which should then appear to be a 32GB drive, but it should work fine.

Example

    # image 32GB usb
      dd if=/dev/sdf of=image_original.raw bs=32M status=progress

    # dup onto 64GB usb
      dd if=image_original.raw of=/dev/sdg bs=32M status=progress

Comment: Yea I've tried all of that, I've been working on this case for about the last 2 weeks.. and it doesn't seem to work as intended. I have had success in taking 5gb of the custom image and dispersing it to other 32gb usb's though. Thats the only reason I bothered to comment on your question in reference to it. Is because you could be running into similar issue!

Comment: I think I've identified an immediate problem. I thought that the RAID mirror presented as a disk would not include the RAID metadata contained in the last sector. If I look at the md126 RAID drive with a hex editor, I see the metadata. This implies I'm over writing it with an unlimited dd.

Comment: Rick, while unlikely, check that your 64GB usb is actually 64 GB by dd ing zeros to it until it stops. I've run into a few bogus devices that were not what they claimed.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i'll be sure to check that out to rule it out!